# Algorithm choices for trapezoidal decomposition

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

Most textbooks and papers in the computational geometry area use **randomized incremental** algorithms for trapezoidal decomposition in default instead of other algorithms that are easier to understand and program (e.g., sweep line from left to right). Are there any reasons or advantages for this choice?